# A better name instead of light cone

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

Cone means a lot of things in mathematics. For example the right circular cone is a geometric shape with finite size while linear cone is a subset of a vector space which is closed under multiplication by positive scalars. In my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3639527/algebraic-characterization-of-light-cones) I wanted to specify a special cone and with regard to its physical application, I named it "light cone" (more usual name would have been "future light cone" but too much words taken from physics deter matematicians, so I've simplified it). This nomenclature has been criticized, so I want a better name for it. I need a name because I want to include it in the title of my question.

My cone is a linear cone that is the surface of an infinite circular cone in dimensions 3 or 4. This can be defined as the half of the set $C=\{v\in V\mid B(v,v)\}=0$ where $B$ is a bilinear form of signature $(+--)$ (in dimension 3) or $(+---)$ (in dimension 4). "Half" means one of the connected component of $C\setminus \{0\}$ together with $0$.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Occlusion cone ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This misrepresents the criticism expressed in the comments under the linked question. The criticism was (rightly) based on the fact that you called something a “light cone” without any association with an indefinite bilinear form. It was due to mathematicians not being deterred by physics but displaying an understanding of the meaning of the term “light cone” in physics. You're now asking for a name for a cone defined by an indefinite bilinear form, which didn't appear in the linked question. For this cone, the name “light cone” would be appropriate.

Comment: Hmm. Does a name belong to an object or to a definition of it?

Comment: @mma: I'm not sure that question can be answered in that generality. But light is very much a phenomenon associated with the structure of space-time characterized by an indefinite signature. You could of course also call an orange cone on a construction site a (truncated) "light cone", since it's a forward cone that has the same shape as a light cone if you forget about the Minkowski structure. The fact that no one does seems to indicate that it's not just the geometric shape of things but also the structural context that influences how we call things.